# Why use parameter set $\theta$ in Bayes Rule

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

[image]

I understood the Bayes rules described in the above equation

[image]

However in the above equation, class y replaced by parameter set $\theta $

**I want to know why we don't immediately use y, but we use the parameter set $\theta$ of a function that takes $x$ as input and predicts $y$**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should not attach fixed meaning to notations! They vary from setting to setting as in the two equations displayed in the question where $P$ enjoys multiple interpretations: density of $X$, density of $Y$, density of $\theta$, conditional density of $Y$ given $X$, &tc...

Bayes' theorem can be expressed in terms of probabilities
$$\mathbb P(A|B) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(B|A)\times\mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(B)}$$
which can also be written in terms of random variables $X$ and $Y$
$$\mathbb P(Y\in A|X\in B) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(X\in B|Y\in A)\times\mathbb P(Y\in A)}{\mathbb P(X\in B)}$$
as in the special case
$$\mathbb P(Y=y|X=x) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(X=x|Y=y)\times\mathbb P(Y=y)}{\mathbb P(X=x)}$$
when $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{y\}$ (and both $X$ and $Y$ have a countable support). And it can also be expressed in terms of densities for random variables $X$ and $Y$ (wrt the appropriate dominating measures):
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\dfrac{f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)}{f_X(x)}$$
which also applies for the pair of rv's $X$ and $\theta$:
$$f_{\theta|X}(\theta|x)=\dfrac{f_{X|\theta}(x|\theta)f_\theta(\theta)}{f_X(x)}$$
(except that the same notation $\theta$ is customarily (ab)used for representing both rv and realisation).

In the case the distribution of a discrete random variable $Y$ is parameterised by an unknown parameter $\theta$ that is informed by the observation $x$ of a random variable $X$,
$$\underbrace{\mathbb P(Y=y|X=x)}_{\text{predictive}}=\int_\Theta \mathbb P(Y=y|\theta) \underbrace{f_{\theta|X}(\theta|x)}_{\text{posterior}}\,\text d\theta$$

Comment: The first sentence should be written before the beginning of any chapter in a textbook. +1.

Answer (score 1):

This difference between the two articulations of Bayes' rule really just comes down to what is being measured.

In the first case, the expression is solving for the probability of some outcome `y` given the input variables `X`.

In the second case, the expression is solving for the probability of the observed set of parameter values, given the set of input variables `X`.